# Strange Network issue

Tags: networking, routing, switch, mpls

No Internet access for all workstations
Internet working for some servers, eg. DC

MPLS network > Switch > workstation
MPLS network > Switch > server

Workstation troubleshooting 
 - tracert google doesn't make a single hop
 - local gateway and DC pingable
 - Ipconfig set correctly
 - check routes
 - no firewall

DC troubleshooting

- DC can access google
- same gateway
- Tracert www.google.com works fine
- ping other sites works fine
- check routes

Unable to unplug the network as this site DC is the PDC and exchange server is also on this site and still working correctly for other users.

Please advise of any additional troubleshooting I can take to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You've tried to ping www.google.com from the workstation subnet, but havn't stated if they can actually resolve the name. If they can, which dns servers are they using, are they local or the other side of the MPLS?

Try running a tracert to something like 8.8.8.8 (google DNS) to rule out DNS resolution issues.

Also please provide the output of:

```
route print
```

From a computer on each side of the MPLS.

It would also be useful to know more about your network, e.g. details of the subnets each side, the gateway addresses on each side, and how your internet is provisioned i.e. if a local router hands traffic bound from clients to servers over the MPLS and all other traffic out over a seperate internet connection, or whether it's all passed over MPLS and internet connectivity is provided by the MPLS provider via a break-out.

Finally, verify there is actually connectivity to the client's DNS servers, and also across the MPLS by pinging it or using nslookup, if the DNS servers are on the other side of the MPLS then run a trace-route to these servers too.